# Delete sent push notification in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to delete sent push notification in React Native (in both android and iOS) app. Scenario is if user A sent a friend request to user B and cancel  friend request after push notification received by B then push notification should be removed from B's push notifications. In my app i don't use VoIP

Comment: once the push notification in received by a user . it can't be deleted by a sender .

Comment: @sachinmathew WhatsApp and hangout are done the same thing

Comment: what about sending anathor silent push notification to destroy current notification in the app

Comment: @sachinmathew silent notification received at killed state of app are notified in ios

Comment: https://medium.com/@m.imadali10/ios-silent-push-notifications-84009d57794c

Answer (score 4):

On cancelling the friend request sent another silent push notification

and on receiving silent notification delete the first notification by notification ID

```
removeDeliveredNotification(notificationId) returns Promise containing void;
```